# Angular Material Datepicker Popup position

Tags: angular, angular-material

[image: Issue]

Is there is any property to show the popup below input? because It's disturbing my UI. Please help me out

Comment: Angular material datepicker popup position depends on the space you have between input field and browser bottom/ top. The documentation might help you to get proper understanding on material datepicker: [link](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples)

Comment: Did you solved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The same issue I was facing a few days back. Make sure you have added a theme CSS style sheet at the right place:- basically it should be placed inside the style.css.

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

check in your angular.json/.angular-cli.json which global css file referring to, add the theme import in the same file

```
 "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
```

Comment: OP seems to have a working datepicker - not sure how this answer will help him solve his question.

Comment: @Edric -what i understood from this question is , he has problem with some style or alignment only, where i shared my experience on the same issue how i resolved.